# Trying to access phpMyAdmin but there's a configuration error

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I keep getting this error when I try to use the XAMPP control panel to launch Apache and access phpMyAdmin on my local host.
I don't really know how to proceed to change the config or anything since im only a frontend developer (I need to do this to create a custom form for my client)

Would really appreciate some help regarding this as I can't move forward if I can't access the phpMyAdmin dashboard

[image: phpMyAdmin error message]

Comment: Does the xampp control panel show that mysql (or possibly mariadb) is definitely up and running? That service needs to be active, otherwise there's nothing for phpmyadmin to connect to

Comment: `I can't move forward if I can't access the phpMyAdmin dashboard`...FYI there are other ways and tools to interact with the database too. All you need is any mysql-compatible admin tool, and the correct credentials